# Setting the Cell width and Height in Excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project in Excel-VBA, for copying rows and paste it into a new sheet, wherein, it will automatically sort the rows by date using 1 column. However, After pasting those rows in another sheet, the cell Height is being thin, I don't know how that happens, can someone help me with setting its height depending on the height of another cell?

I have here a code for setting the height but it doesn't work.

```
Rows("3:25").RowHeight = 25
```

I have a code that will Unmerged, Sort, And Remerge the cells in excel using VBA, But it cannot sort the Rows because I have 2 range. the 1st range is "A10: AA350" for unmerging and populating the co-cells and the second range is "A10: DZ350" for sorting.

```
'Unmerged, Sorting, and Remerging of Cells and Rows
Sub Sort()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim address As String
Dim contents As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngNew As Range
On Error GoTo myErr

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAMPLE")

Set myRange = ws.Range("A5:AA350")

Set rngNew = ws.Range("A5:DZ350")
' Get lstrow from Column N, if Column A has merged cells
lstrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

' Unmerge and populate
For Each rng In myRange
    If rng.MergeCells Then
        ' Get value from top left cell
        contents = rng.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value
        address = rng.MergeArea.address
        rng.UnMerge
        ws.Range(address).Value = contents
    End If
Next rng

' Sort
rngNew.Sort key1:=ws.Range("Q5:Q" & lstrow), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

' Turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Re-merge
With ws
    For l = 5 To lstrow


        If .Cells(l, 10).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 10).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 17).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 17).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 18).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 18).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 19).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 19).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 20).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 20).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 21).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 21).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 22).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 22).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 23).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 23).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 24).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 24).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 25).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 25).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 26).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 26).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            And .Cells(l, 27).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(l + 1, 27).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value _
            Then

            ' Merge column A
            Range(.Cells(l, 10).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 10)).Merge

            ' Merge column C
            Range(.Cells(l, 17).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 17)).Merge


             Range(.Cells(l, 18).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 18)).Merge

              Range(.Cells(l, 19).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 19)).Merge

               Range(.Cells(l, 20).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 20)).Merge

                Range(.Cells(l, 21).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 21)).Merge

                 Range(.Cells(l, 22).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 22)).Merge

                  Range(.Cells(l, 23).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 23)).Merge

                   Range(.Cells(l, 24).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 24)).Merge

                    Range(.Cells(l, 25).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 25)).Merge

                     Range(.Cells(l, 26).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 26)).Merge

                      Range(.Cells(l, 27).MergeArea, .Cells(l + 1, 27)).Merge


        End If
    Next l
 End With

' Turn on alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

myErr:
    MsgBox "Unable to sort!"
End Sub
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: You need to tell Excel the name of the sheet: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("3:25").RowHeight = 25`

Comment: Ok, Sir. ill do it.

Comment: It works Sir :) Thanks. God Bless!

Comment: I have a Code sir, that will Copy and paste The rows into a new worksheet. :)

Comment: But now sir, I have a problem again for sorting the rows, I change my Range in unmerging and Sorting then Remerge. But it cannot be executed.

Comment: Can you provide a small before and after? (How can I run your code on my machine and see what you mean?)

Comment: What does “cannot be executed” actually mean?

Comment: I'm sorry sir, It will execute, but when it comes to sorting the Msgbox "unable to Sort" pops-up.

Comment: Try: rngNew.Sort key1:=ws.Range("Q5"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

Comment: it does not work sir.

Comment: too poor an error description to build something on...

Comment: @paulbica Can you write an answer so the author can accept your solution please, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to the initial question

---

You need to tell Excel the name of the sheet, example:

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("3:25").RowHeight = 25
> ```